# Cloth Simulation Explosion

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to simulate a simple blanket onto the bed (a plane subdivided 20 times). All the objects that the blanket will fall are set as collisions. The cloth has self-collisions turned on. The simulation was cached. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thanks.

This is the blend file: pasteall.org/blend/8e4c1cc2d10e4a6d876a66314851fa33
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file (only the cloth and one collision object): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/8e4c1cc2d10e4a6d876a66314851fa33

Answer (score 5):

The following seemed to help:

1. Increase the quality step from your rather low number (i used 55)
2. For the collision object i decreased the Outer Thickness (to the default of 0.02)

Here's my smooth result at frame 23 (i cut down to a 30 frame simulation to save time):

[image]

and the changed [image] file

next time consider the https://blend-exchange.com/ uploader that is more convenient to post your blend file.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, the simulation works but only up until frame 23. After that, it just shriveled up like a piece of wrinkly paper. Does that mean I have to increase the quality steps again? Why does this happen in Blender?

Comment: @Ming -- do you mean frame 23 in YOUR file or in my Solution file?  My file that I uploaded (from you file that I downloaded) shows no shriveling or explosion.   Indeed you should have an adequate number of quality steps.  Seems like 55 was sufficient, perhaps even 30.

Comment: I tried to replicate your results in my file (quality steps and reverting back to the default outer thickness). The problem persists. I then tried to increase the outer thickness after watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0ziiFFEbJo. I then tried to isolate the bed/table/blanket to its own blender file but it gets worse the more stuff I want the blanket to collide with. What should I be looking out for when a cloth object needs to collide with multiple objects?

Comment: Here is the blend file.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=5EDNow6m" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5EDNow6m/)

Comment: @Ming -- I had a quick look at the video.   Is there a time unit where they suggest setting the outer thickness to higher than the default 0.02?  I couldn't find that.  I see it set to 0.02 at time unit 2:39.